# Is there a way to easily switch a lot of code dependent on SqlConnection to MySqlConnection

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server

I have an Old application which has more than 200,000 lines of code.

Its currently using MS Sql Express as its data store. There are stored procedures being called and the CURD functionality is implemented through table adapters mostly.

Since the SqlExpress comes with a 10 GB limit, I am trying to change the application to use a MySql database.

I used the Migration wizard that comes with mysql workbench to import all the data.

Now for the problem I am facing.

In the current code, there is a Singleton Connection Manager that is accessed like this

```
var connection = ConnectionManager.GetInstance().GetNewSQLConnection();
            if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed) connection.Open();
            int? iErrorNumber = 0;
            DataTable dt;
            string sErrorMessage = "";
            try
            {
                SqlParameter[] paramsToStore = new SqlParameter[3];
                paramsToStore[0] = new SqlParameter("@iErrorNumber", SqlDbType.Int);
                paramsToStore[0].Value = iErrorNumber;
                paramsToStore[1] = new SqlParameter("@sErrorMessage", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
                paramsToStore[1].Size = 8000;
                paramsToStore[1].Value = sErrorMessage;
                paramsToStore[2] = new SqlParameter("@iAssayPK", iAssayPK);
                dt = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(connection, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "USP_ASY_AssayUseCount", paramsToStore).Tables[0];
            }
```

here is the extracted interface for the ConnectionManager

```
public interface IConnectionManager
    {
        string GenerateDBUsername(string _sDatabase, string _sUsername);
        Connection GetConnection();
        Connection GetCurrentConnection();
        SqlConnection GetNewSQLConnection();
        string GetOrmConnectionString();
        void SetCurrentConnection(Connection _oConCurrentConnection);
        void UpdateConnection(Connection _oTheConnection, bool _bSavePassword, string _sNameBeforeUpdate, string ServerAddress);
    }
```

As you can see the GetNewSQLConnection() returns an SqlConnection object.
There are hundreds of places where this connection is used.
and most of the time it is being passed to tableAdapter like this

```
using (CustomNamesTableAdapter tadaCustomNames = new CustomNamesTableAdapter())
            {
                try
                {
                    tadaCustomNames.Connection = ConnectionManager.GetInstance().GetNewSQLConnection();
                    tadaCustomNames.Fill(_dtblToFill, ref iErrorNumber, ref sErrorMessage);
                    if (iErrorNumber != 0)
                    {
                        ErrorLogManager.GetInstance().WriteDBError(DateTime.Now, (int)iErrorNumber, sErrorMessage, "USP_CSN_GetCustomNames", this.GetType().ToString(), "void GetCustomerNames(CommonDataSet.CustomNamesDataTable _dtblToFill)", "Error while executing SP");
                        throw new BDRException(Globals.BDRMessageType.EXCEPTION, DateTime.Now, 46, "Error while executing SP");
                    }
                }
```

I thought if I can inherit the SqlConnection Class I would be able to make a     class maybe I can do something with that trying to combine the SqlConnection and MySqlConneciton into a single object and using the underlying object depending on the current database selected.

but the Table adapters that I am looking at are also using other types from System.Data.SqlClient like parameters and trying to update all that code would mean changing the code a LOT of places ....

I know this would have been very different is the application was built using an ORM but since its not .. I am looking for suggestion on how to solve this.

If I can somehow use interfaces and use different implementations (with different databases), that should be way to go, but since all the code is already depends on typed( SqlConnection, Sql.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand etc) parameters I dont see a way to avoid this..

the other options are to buy Sql Standard which is infinitely more expensive that the express edition. or try to archive old data that is not being used actively and keep the database size below the limit, or maybe create multiple 'Data' databases (Data that the application works on) and use one of them for application data (users/roles/etc)

Just a thought here, if this application would have been written in python ... would it have been easier to make a change of this type ?

Comment: I am afraid if your codebase is that deeply dependent on that namespace, this will be a major redesign. You should probably consider to first switch to design that abstracts better from the concrete DB and then change to MySQL in a second step.

Comment: Yes, building an abstraction layer is necessary to avoid future pain if re-factoring has to go ahead.

Comment: ADO.NET classes implement interfaces, [abstract classes and class factories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/factory-model-overview). Switching from one provider to the other could be as simple as changing a setting in app.config, as long as the application uses `DbConnection`, `DbCommand` etc. It's no different in Python. If you use provider-specific classes you'll have trouble migrating

Comment: BTW that code is awful - it looks like it tried to emulate the class factory without any benefits and even *harms* performance by using a singleton connection instead of the default connection pooling. I bet there's a lot of fiddling going on just to prevent those global connections and transactions from blocking each other. I'd be more concerned about how MySQL is going to react to that

Comment: BTW SQL Server Express 2016 SP1 and later added transparent partitioning, compression, columnstore indexes. You can now compress tables *transparently* (and improve performance by reducint IO), move old partitions to other storage or even offline with simple commands that take *no time* at all. You may not have a 10GB issue any more

Comment: Given the bad state of the code I'd suggest using SQL Server Express 2017 with selected compression first, partitioning the data by year and moving old data out. It's far less risky than trying to migrate to another database with such brittle code. This may alleviate the problem altogether. In any case it'll buy you time to clean up at least the data access code and either move to ADO.NET's class-factory model or introduce a real ORM like EF Core/NH or a microORM like Dapper. That `GetOrmConnectionString()` is very suspicious - did someone try to build a custom ORM?

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos That GetOrmConnectionString is me, Since the connection is already made and the connection string is available, I used an ORM by DevExpress (very similar to EF) to try to expand on the pattern that you can see here.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos its not just awful code ... its also a pretty neat design(sarcasm). This multi user application directly connects to the database, and all users are given a database login .... which needs to have securityadmin prevelage on the sql server so that it can be used to create more users.

Comment: @tanveery given the size of the code and how deeply integrated it is, it will take more time to refactor it than to make the whole application again as mentioned by Fildor. if that stage comes, I would first split this single application into a two applications where one application is the client and the other one resides with the database and implement everything over REST. since the business logic is already written Asp.Net core seems like option to go for the server-side component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced a very similar situation some time ago but in that case I had to migrate MySQL code to SQL Server code.

The bottom line is that you have to refactor the code. Not only at the .NET level but also your stored procedures will have to be updated as well as the SQL Server stored procedures are not 100% compatible with MySQL stored procedures. There are syntactical differences.

The good news is that the ADO.NET code in terms of SQL Server versus MySQL are very similar. After all, SqlConnection and MySqlConnection inherit from the same class DbConnection. Similarly, SqlDataAdapter and MySqlDataAdapter inherit from the same class DbDataAdapter. This is true for every other ADO.NET class.

You can obviously go ahead and refactor the existing ADO.NET and stored procedures code. However, in my case, I didn't choose that approach. Instead, I treated it more of implementing an additional data provider. That way, my existing data access code remained untouched. This probably was more work but it ensured that I can go back to my previous implementation at any time I wanted for whatever reasons.

You have another option which you should consider. How about using cloud-based database say Azure Sql Database? That way, it would cost you only for the size and performance tier you choose.

Comment: ADO.NET is based on class factories. If the code needs to be portable, it should use the abstract classes only and create instances using the class factories. The provider to use can be configured in app.config or web.config

Comment: Yes, when it comes to re-design and re-factoring code then sky is the limit! The question is whether it's a good idea to keep existing implementation as it is and construct a new one with interfaces that bind both the implementations to a common contract.

Comment: given the state of the posted code? This looks it was written pre-2005 by someone trying to build his/her own ORM - check all those `GetConnection`, `GetCurrentConnection`, `GetNewSQLConnection` and `GetOrmConnectionString` methods. The concurrency model differences between SQL Server and MySQL could cause quite a few problems

Comment: Or the apparently eternal connection - I shudder to think about lock accumulation and transactions

Comment: I don't want to judge the design of the code. Yes, it looks bit unconventional. I just wanted to make sure I provide my best possible advice to solve the problem at hand. Of course, if he has the time and money to re-design the code then he probably would be better off to do so.

Comment: @tanveery honestly I think this is the best way to go in the long run. rather than building on the current model and ending up even more restricted later on. I was trying to be lazy and avoid this if possible :D